# How to remove specific item in INI file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ini

I want to remove specific item in my INI file.
My INI file

```
[Information]
Name= Joyce
Class=Elementry
Age=10
```

I want to remove `Age=10`

I tried this code, but I just can remove the value of `Age` which is `10`.

```
Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $a,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $b,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $c
    )
    Import-Module PsIni
    $ff = Get-IniContent $FilePath
    $ff["$a"]["$b"] = "$c"  
    $ff | Out-IniFile -FilePath $FilePath -Force
```

My Expectation output of INI file is:

```
[Information]
Name=Joyce
Class=Elementry
```

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions about ini files. Have you considered more modern approach and use JSON or XML instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-IniContent` returns a (nested) ordered hashtable that represents the INI file's structure.

To remove an entry, you must therefore use the ordered hashtable's `.Remove()` method:

```
# Read the INI file into a (nested) ordered hashtable.
$iniContent = Get-IniContent file.ini

# Remove the [Information] section's 'Age' entry.
$iniContent.Information.Remove('Age')

# Save the updated INI representation back to disk.
$iniContent | Out-File -Force file.ini
```

You could therefore modify your script as follows:

```
Param(
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $FilePath,
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $Section,
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $EntryKey,
                               $EntryValue # optional: if omitted, remove the entry
)

Import-Module PsIni

$ff = Get-IniContent $FilePath

if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('EntryValue')) {
  $ff.$Section.$EntryKey = $EntryValue
} else {    
  $ff.$Section.Remove($EntryKey)
}

$ff | Out-IniFile -FilePath $FilePath -Force
```

Then call it as follows; note the omission of a 4th argument, which requests removal of the entry:

```
.\script.ps1 file.ini Information Age
```